# Angular Pipe or Directive: Get real value of Input field instead of modified value from pipe or directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-pipe

I've created a custom pipe which is replacing the input value with asterisks and added space between 4 characters below the code

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'creditCard'
})
export class CreditCardPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any) {
    if (value === undefined) {
      return value;
    }
    const s = value.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/([\w*]{4})/g,'$1 ').trim();
    return s.replace(/\w/g, '*');
  }

}
```

I've applied this pipe to the Input field(formcontrol) and it is working as expected, but if I tried to get the value of the field getting the asterisks.

```
  <input name="creditcardnumber" formControlName="creditCardNumber"
                      [value]="totalDueNewCardForm.get('creditCardNumber').value | creditCard"
                      type="text" appNumbersOnly required />
```

Is there any way to get the real value of formcontrol instead of pipe value.

**Tried another way to make this happen with Directive**

I've created a custom directive which is replacing the input value with asterisks and added space between 4 characters below the code

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import {NgControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appNumbersOnly]'
})
export class NumbersOnlyDirective {

  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*){0,1}$/g);

  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab'];


  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private model: NgControl) {
  }
  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  inputChange(event: any) {
    debugger;

    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
       this.model.control.setValue(event.target.value.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/([\w*]{4})/g,'$1 ').trim().replace(/\w/g,'*'));
         }
}
```

I've applied this directive to the Input field(formcontrol) and it is working as expected, but if I tried to get the value of the field getting the asterisks.

```
<input type="text" formControlName="firstName" required appNumbersOnly>
```

Is there any way to change the appearance and make the formcontrol value as is. or any other solution for this

Comment: I don't think using a `pipe` with the `value` property on a Service is going to do that. You should be better off using a directive instead.

Comment: Looks like you should use type="password" instead of text field.

Comment: @siddAjmera, I'm aslo thinking the same, do you have any kind of example with this?

Comment: @SiddAjmera tried using directive as well could you take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please can you check the example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-g1xn3v

Answer (score -1):

check it out.

```
import { Component,Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup,FormControl,FormBuilder, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent  {
      formGroup: FormGroup;
      creditCardNumber: FormControl = new FormControl();

      value = 12312312312321;

       getValueFromInput(){
        console.log(this.formGroup.get('credit').value)
      }

      constructor(
        private _fb: FormBuilder
      ) {

      }
      ngOnInit(){
        this.formGroup = this._fb.group({
          credit: ['123123']
        });  }
    }
```

in HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <input name="creditcardnumber" formControlName="creditCardNumber" 
  [value]="formGroup.get('credit').value | creditCard"
  type="text"  />
</form>

 <button (click)="getValueFromInput()">View</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your example code will always transform credit card number to asterisk.

You may consider writing directive `credit-card-mask` OR use `angular-ui-mask`  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask will not work in angular, its angularjs library.

Comment: Agree!  Here is a npm pkg for Ng2 https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-text-mask